# changing django model filed data before saving to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i want to update model field data before saving to database.

```
class mynumber(TimeStampedModel):
 
 
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    number = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
```

```
#serializer file
 
class mynumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = mynumber
        fields = "__all__"
```

```
#view
class mynumberViewSet(CreateListMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
 
    serializer_class = mynumberSerializer
    queryset = mynumber.objects.all()
```

i want to divide number field by 2 before saving to database.
what should be the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is overriding the `def save()` method of your model `class mynumber`.

`def save()` method is going to run when `example_object.save()` is invoked on an object and you can access it's fields like this before saving into database. So you can override the save() method of your model,

```
class Example(models.Model):
    text= models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=None, decimal_places=None)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.number = self.number / 2
        super(Example, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a similar thing for after instance save? Like can I do something like [this] (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#:~:text=schema.post(%27save%27%2C%20function(doc)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%27%25s%20has%20been%20saved%27%2C%20doc._id)%3B%0A%7D)%3B)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is, you can use Signals for that purpose in Django. For example right after a new user instance is saved to database, you can make an API request with that user instance fields added to the request. Detailed documentation for Django Signals (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/)